# Error syncing load balancer: failed to ensure load balancer: failed to build load-balancer

Tags: kubernetes, github-actions, digital-ocean

We are only trying out the Kubernetes setup and strictly following the docs (at this point).
We are on DigitalOcean and there is a bunch of tutorials and docs related to it as well (added all of these below for a reference).

At this point, I managed to deploy the two pods and now trying to configure the load balancer for them in the simplest way possible. Everything is getting deployed, but load balancer is failing to be initialized with the following error:

```
Error syncing load balancer: failed to ensure load balancer: failed to build load-balancer request: specified health check port 8080 does not exist on service default/https-with-cert
```

I verified that the health check is actually working on the pods if I ping them directly. In fact, this is the same health check that we are using for the last 2 years in manually setup infrastructure.

The build is running through github actions and everything is passing without issues:

[image]

where deployment.yml looks like this:

```
---
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: https-with-cert
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/do-loadbalancer-protocol: "http"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/do-loadbalancer-algorithm: "round_robin"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/do-loadbalancer-tls-ports: "443"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/do-loadbalancer-certificate-id: "c1eae56c-42cd-4953-9ab9-1a6facae87f8"
    # "api.priz.guru" should be configured to point at the IP address of the DO load-balancer
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/do-loadbalancer-hostname: "api.priz.guru"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/do-loadbalancer-enable-proxy-protocol: "true"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/do-loadbalancer-disable-lets-encrypt-dns-records: "false"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/do-loadbalancer-size-unit: "2"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/do-loadbalancer-healthcheck-port: "8080"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/do-loadbalancer-healthcheck-protocol: "http"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/do-loadbalancer-healthcheck-path: "/v1/ping"
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: priz-api
  ports:
    - name: http
      protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 8080
    - name: https
      protocol: TCP
      port: 443
      targetPort: 8080
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: priz-api
  labels:
    app: priz-api
spec:
  # modify replicas according to your case
  replicas: 2
  strategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: priz-api
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: priz-api
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: priz-api
          image: <IMAGE>
          env:
            - name: PRIZ_DATABASE_URL
              value: "${PRIZ_DATABASE_URL_PROD}"
            - name: PRIZ_DATABASE_USER
              value: "${PRIZ_DATABASE_USER_PROD}"
            - name: PRIZ_DATABASE_PASSWORD
              value: "${PRIZ_DATABASE_PASSWORD_PROD}"
            - name: PRIZ_AUTH0_DOMAIN
              value: "${PRIZ_AUTH0_DOMAIN_PROD}"
            - name: PRIZ_AUTH0_API_DOMAIN
              value: "${PRIZ_AUTH0_API_DOMAIN_PROD}"
            - name: PRIZ_AUTH0_API_CLIENT_ID
              value: "${PRIZ_AUTH0_API_CLIENT_ID_PROD}"
            - name: PRIZ_AUTH0_API_CLIENT_SECRET
              value: "${PRIZ_AUTH0_API_CLIENT_SECRET_PROD}"
            - name: PRIZ_APP_BASE_URL
              value: "${PRIZ_APP_BASE_URL_PROD}"
            - name: PRIZ_STRIPE_API_KEY_SECRET
              value: "${PRIZ_STRIPE_API_KEY_SECRET_PROD}"
            - name: PRIZ_SEARCH_HOST
              value: "${PRIZ_SEARCH_HOST_PROD}"
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
          resources:
            requests:
              cpu: 500m
              memory: 500Mi
            limits:
              cpu: 2000m
              memory: 2000Mi
```

How do I even debug this issue? What is missing?

Some references that we used:
https://docs.digitalocean.com/products/kubernetes/how-to/add-load-balancers/
https://docs.digitalocean.com/products/kubernetes/how-to/configure-load-balancers/
https://github.com/digitalocean/digitalocean-cloud-controller-manager/tree/master/docs/controllers/services/examples

Comment: Did you try changing `service.beta.kubernetes.io/do-loadbalancer-healthcheck-port` to 80?

Comment: Yes, in that case, it does not complain about this error, but the ping still does not work. Somehow, it uses some 31xxx port for the health checks.

Comment: Load balancers don't talk to pods directly; they talk to the nodes and the node has to translate the health check request to an internal IP within the cluster's service address range. The port 31xxx is a port on the node itself.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is the same issue but I had the same error message on following the steps at

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-nginx-ingress-on-digitalocean-kubernetes-using-helm

In fact it worked the first time around but I had deleted the cluster and was testing on a new cluster to be sure I had my now modified scripts working from scratch ...

Second time around I got the above error

So I stepped through the instructions again and noticed

> This setup will use a DigitalOcean Kubernetes cluster with three nodes, but you could also create a cluster manually.

To save costs I had setup a single node cluster

So I started again with the default 3 node cluster and it worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Azure user here, so this may be a little bit different for DigitalOcean, but here goes anyways!

When the cloud provider offers you a load balancer, depending on the cloud provider's configuration, either the kubelet or the control plane needs permissions to make changes to the load balancer when the network layout changes (such as when new nodes come online, and when existing nodes go offline, as a couple of examples, though there are other conditions that change the network layout as well).

When you get this error, it's because one of those 2 components of the cluster is missing the permissions it requires.

In Azure, for example, when we create a cluster, the control plane and kubelet have access to edit resources in the same resource group. So if we create the network in a different resource group, then we have to manually add a role assignment to the cluster's subnet in the network's resource group which gives the control plane and kubelet permissions to make changes to that subnet.

A quick read over the DigitalOcean docs confirms that what Azure calls resource groups, DigitalOcean calls projects. I suspect that you may have your load balancer, VPC, and cluster (or some combination of the 3) in different projects, so you'll need to associate them all with the same project.